# calling a form based on the inputs in php

Tags: php, mysql, forms

This question may just seem so simple for everyone of you but I don't know how to implement this.

I am generating a report. My report has monthly, and daily report. I have a drop down list to choose between monthly and daily... My problem is that How can I make a submit button that would direct me to monthly or daily page when I click one of the option in the drop down list (monthly or daily) based on the time i have also inputted. Help please...

(i have a MySQL database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the report generation, so you can post to the same URL (say, `createReport.php`):

```
if ($_POST['period'] == 'daily') 
{
    include('reports/dailyReport.php');
}
elseif ($_POST['period'] == 'monthly') 
{
    include('reports/monthlyReport.php');
}
else
{
    include('error/noSuchReport.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the action of the form say (form.php) and pass variables to this file

in this file write a code like this :

```
    <?php
    if($_REQUEST['x']=='something')
    {
         include('somefile.php');
    }
    else
    {
         include('someotherfile.php');
    }
    ?>
```

i think this is one way